# How to send integer via bluetooth to Arduino in WP8?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, bluetooth, arduino

I am making an application where I need to send my phone's accelerometer readings to my Arduino via bluetooth. I am able to send strings easily but, I am getting errors when I am altering the function for integers. 
Here is the code I used:

```
private async void BT2Arduino_Sendint(int value)
{
       if (BTSock == null)
       {
           txtBTStatus.Text = "No connection found. Try again!";
           return;
        }
        else
            if (BTSock != null)
            {
               byte[] buffer = new byte[] { Convert.ToByte(value) };
               var datab = GetBufferFromByteArray(UTF8Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(buffer, 0, 4));                  await BTSock.OutputStream.WriteAsync(datab);               
               txtBTStatus.Text = "Connected to the Device";
            }
 }


private IBuffer GetBufferFromByteArray(byte[] package)
{
    using (DataWriter dw = new DataWriter())
    {
        dw.WriteBytes(package);
        return dw.DetachBuffer();
    }
}
```

The error is basically in the line where I am using UTF8 encoding. It says ***"The best overloaded method match for System.Text.Encoding.GetBytes(char[], int, int) has some invalid arguments"***
Please help me resolve this issue as soon as you can. I know I am doing a mistake with the basics, but I don't have much knowledge with Encoding. Thanks for any help you can provide. :)

Answer (score 0):

Apparently the first parameter of `System.Text.Encoding.GetBytes` needs to be a char array and not a byte array.

Comment: In that case, I won't be able to send 'integers' and that is the purpose I want solved. :\

Answer (score 0):

To me looks like you can simply use BitConverter class replacing the code:

```
if (BTSock != null)
{
    byte[] buffer = new byte[] { Convert.ToByte(value) };
    var datab = GetBufferFromByteArray(UTF8Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(buffer, 0, 4));                  
    await BTSock.OutputStream.WriteAsync(datab);               
    txtBTStatus.Text = "Connected to the Device";
}
```

with:

```
if (BTSock != null)
{
    byte[] datab = BitConverter.GetBytes(value);
    await BTSock.OutputStream.WriteAsync(datab);               
    txtBTStatus.Text = "Connected to the Device";
}
```